# finding next prime number of x in C

Tags: c, primes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_prime(int num);
int next_pr(int num);

int main()
{
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d\n", next_pr(num));

    return 0;
}

int next_pr(int num)
{
    int c;
    if (num == 2)
        c = 3;
    else
    {
        num += 2;
        is_prime(num) ? next_pr(num) : c = num;
    }

    return c;
}

int is_prime(int num)
{
    int i;
    int c = 0;
    // printf ("%f\n", sqrt (num));
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); ++i)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
            // printf ("%d\n",num%i);
            c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Write the code as you'd like to see it, maybe in an editor, maybe in the edit box.  Make sure you use spaces instead of tabs; it makes life easier.  Then, when you're done, select the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it.

Comment: Question is not written. and This program is not correct.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of the code, but there isn't a question in the question body.  Please add an explanation of what you get, what you expect, and why you're having problems fixing it.

Comment: i dont know where to write it! it gets a number and returns the next prime number. e.g: 7---> 11   or 13 --->17

Comment: So, edit the question (there's an edit link under the [tag:primes] tag), and add a brief explanation of what the code is supposed to do, and address what it does do.  Don't indent this text at all.  You might need to think about what happens if you enter 4; it isn't 2, so you add 2 to it, yielding 6, and then go off and look for primes, so you skip the correct answer, 5.  You seem to be using recursion, but you don't capture the value returned by the recursive call to `next_pr()`.

Comment: yes, thx ill make the changes

Answer (score 1):

```
int next_pr(int num){
    int c;
    if(num < 2)
        c = 2;
    else if (num == 2)
        c = 3;
    else if(num & 1){
        num += 2;
        c = is_prime(num) ? num : next_pr(num);
    } else
        c = next_pr(num-1);

    return c;
}

int is_prime(int num){
    if((num & 1)==0)
        return num == 2;
    else {
        int i, limit = sqrt(num);
        for (i = 3; i <= limit; i+=2){
            if (num % i == 0)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```